# chroot ssh users to home directory

Tags: ssh, chroot, account-restrictions

How can one chroot ssh users to their home directories?

This is what i have set in my sshd_config file:

```
ChrootDirectory %h

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

ssh version is 6.6.1

This is the error i get when trying to log in:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/user: No such file or directory

/bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to chroot your users to their directories, you need to have the shell & other things they would need to exec in their directories. Which is what your error saying. Chroot is changing root to /home/user, then tries to find /bin/bash (user's shell of choice) in /home/user/bin/bash, fails & reports the error.

Answer (score 2):

The first error message ("Could not `chdir`...") is coming from **ChrootDirectory** in your `sshd_config`.  From the documentation:

> **ChrootDirectory**
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to `chroot(2)` to after
>   authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-owned
>   directories that are not writable by any other user or group.  After
>   the chroot, `sshd(8)` changes the working directory to the user's home
>   directory.

*After* attempting the chroot is when the problem occurs about not being able to find `bash`.  This is related to not having the entire chroot environment setup (see the documentation for `chroot(2)`).

If you want the user's interactive environment to be `chroot`'d (not just `sftp`)you have a lot of work to do.  Depending on your ultimate goal, you may want to simply use a restricted shell instead (check out `bash(1)` and `vim(1)` and search for "restricted" to find some ideas of how to set things up).

I found a couple of other references to similar questions on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) and on [archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) (be sure to scroll to the bottom of the second one for a description of why the directory must be root owned).

Comment: it is unable to find /bin/bash and thus giving the error, that much is understandable. But why is it unable to find the user home directory?
All components of the pathname are root owned and not writable by any other user or group.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit:  someone else has write authority.  If the directory is /home/username, you need to check /home/username, /home, and /, to ensure that all are owned by root and all permissions are go-w.